# VB .net: How to disable/enable buttons depends who's logged in (admin account vs. ordinary account)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, button, authentication

I'm almost done with my project and just asked my teacher for an extension. By the way, here's the last problem that I've been trying to figure out.


So what I would like to do is that when "admin" is logged in, the "ADD" and "REMOVE" buttons are enabled or shown from the other form. So this is how my login form looks like:

```
Public Class LoginForm

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Show()
    UsernameTextBox.Focus()
    AcceptButton = LoginButton

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click

    Dim login = LoginTableAdapter.UserPasswordString(UsernameTextBox.Text, PassTextBox.Text)

    If login Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Username and Password did not match.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        UsernameTextBox.Text = ""
        PassTextBox.Text = ""
        UsernameTextBox.Focus()

    Else
        MsgBox("Welcome!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Me.Hide()
        SearchForm.Show()

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    End

End Sub

Private Sub UsernameTextBox_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles UsernameTextBox.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

So all of my users are connected to my MS Access database. But what I would like to do is that whenever "admin" and "1234" (as password) were logged in, the "ADD" and "Remove" buttons will enable but for example I logged in "userme" and "1234" (as password) the buttons will disappear or disable. Guys, plea se bear with me and thank you.

**BEST ANSWER:**

So thank you so much guys for sharing your answers. So this is the code that I used and it doesn't matter where you wanna put it, either to your Login form or to the second form. I actually put it inside a timer and it worked flawlessly.

```
     Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If LoginForm.UsernameTextBox.Text = "admin" Then
        RemoveButton.Visible = True
        AddButton.Visible = True

    Else
        RemoveButton.Visible = False
        AddButton.Visible = False

    End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: How is an admin used determined?  Simply based on the name, or is there a flag or code of some sort on the user record?  Whatever the case, you need to evaluate the status and return a flag or something to indicate that.  Your `login` apparently just tells you if the name and PW are correct, but nothing about the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you just check the user name on load and enable and diable the button that way?

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
Me.Show()
UsernameTextBox.Focus()

If UserNameTextBox = "Admin" then 
   ExitButton.Visible = False
   AddButton.Visible = False

Else 
   ExitButton.Visible = True
   AddButton.Visible = True



AcceptButton = LoginButton

End Sub
```

Then in your other Routine

```
   If login Is Nothing or UserNameTextbox <> "admin" Then
    MsgBox("Username and Password did not match.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    UsernameTextBox.Text = ""
    PassTextBox.Text = ""
    UsernameTextBox.Focus()

Else
    MsgBox("Welcome!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Me.Hide()
    SearchForm.Show()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to make 2 button like "addbutton" and "removebutton"
2. Set its properties ".Enabled = False"
3. You can place them on the same form, or make new form called "NewForm"
4. Enter this code in login Form:

> `Public Class Login
>       Private Sub OKButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OKButton.Click
>           If txtUsername.Text <> "" And txtPass.Text <> "" Then
>               If txtUsername.Text = "admin" And txtPass.Text = "1234" Then
>                   MsgBox("Welcome !!!")
>                   NewForm.Show()
>                   NewForm.addbutton.Enabled = True
>                   NewForm.removebutton.Enabled = True
>                   Me.Hide()
>               ElseIf txtUsername.Text = "userme" And txtPass.Text = "1234" Then
>                   MsgBox("Welcome !!!")
>                   NewForm.Show()
>                   'No need to make add and remove button false because 
>                   'Default value Is false, but if you make this 
>                   'back to login form, you need set it back to false
>                   Me.Hide()
>               Else
>                   MsgBox("Username or Password didn't match !!!")
>               End If
>           Else
>               MsgBox("Field cannot be blank !!!")
>           End If
>       End Sub
>   End Class`

If you want to make another user, add another "ElseIF" or Just specified the user and password according to your table on your login account (make a query for each user).